# Can you use either JSON.stringify or URL format in JS fetch() 'body' field?

Tags: javascript, json, networking, fetch

When using `fetch()`, I've seen people write the `body` field either as `body: JSON.stringify(...)` or as `body: prop1=val1&prop2...`. Are both equivalent?

Comment: no, they are not equivalent, the data is in a different format ... the most important part in making the decision about which method you use ... *what does the server expect*

Answer (score 0):

For `fetch`, both are permitted. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), the body may be:

> a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, USVString, or ReadableStream object. Note that a request using the GET or HEAD method cannot have a body.

In your case, assuming `body: prop1=val1&prop2` is a typo and you meant `body: 'prop1=val1&prop2'`, both methods are permitted, because both are putting strings into the `body` property, and strings (`USVString`s) are permitted there.

Of course, you should also make sure the server you're sending the request should be able to parse it. (A server *may* only be expecting a query string parameter, or it may only be expecting JSON, or it may be able to parse both, or it may be able to parse neither)